# Adding text to a gif outputs a very low quality gif

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that will add text to a gif.
When it creates the finished gif it is very low quality with missing pixels (see below).
I'm using the `text-on-gif` module but other similar module produce the same issue.

```
const {Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits} = require("discord.js");
const textOnGif = require("text-on-gif");

const token = "";
const client = new Client({intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });



client.once(Events.ClientReady, c=>{
    console.log(`Bot online. Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
})

client.on("messageCreate", async (message)=>{
    let msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch(message.reference.messageId);
    console.log(msg.content);

    await textOnGif({
        file_path: "https://media.tenor.com/ASPoZ-hJLNQAAAAd/caracal-big.gif",
        textMessage: msg.content,
        write_as_file: true,
        getAsBuffer: false,
        write_path: "./test2.gif"
    });
})

client.login(token);
```

Input (`test1.gif`):
https://media.tenor.com/ASPoZ-hJLNQAAAAd/caracal-big.gif

Output (`test2.gif`):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCoZ7.jpg

Tried already:

- `text-on-gif` module (current implementation, produces the above output)
- `canvas-gif` module produces the same corrupted output
- Downloading the input gif does not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the input gif itself. I am not sure what caused it to produce the cursed output, but every other gif I tried worked flawlessly.